# Problema con librería string.h en c++

Tags: c++, string, ascii

Tengo un string llamado cadena con: `"32+"`

```
string cadena="32+";
```

Y una variable entera `v`

```
int v;
```

Al hacer:

```
v=cadena[0];
```

`v` se le da el valor de `51` (su valor en ASCII)

¿Cómo puedo corregir esto y que le dé el valor de 3?

Comment: No, porque esa variable se usa en una iteración, y hay algunos valores que no se deben cambiar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En ASCII, los digitos del 0 al 9  tienen los valores del 48 al 57, si al valor ASCII del caracter le restas el valor del caracter '0' obtendras el entero que simboliza ese caracter.

```
string cadena="32+";
int v;
v = cadena[0]; // v = 51
v = cadena[0] - 48 // v = 51 - 48 = 3
```

En lugar del numero 48 puedes poner '0', ya que tomara el valor ASCII de ese caracter para realizar la resta y el resultado sera correcto de todas formas

```
v = cadena[0] - '0' // v = 51 - 48 = 3
```

Answer (score 2):

`"32"` son tres caracteres: `'3'`, `'2'`, y `'+'`. Los caracteres se codifican usando tablas de caracteres, como por ejemplo la tabla ASCII. De hecho, usando esa tabla vemos como la codificación numérica de esa secuencia es la siguiente:

```
51 50 43
```

Ahí se ve, por ejemplo, que los caracteres que representan dígitos numericos empiezan a partir de 0x30 (hexadecimal). Se pone en hexadecimal porque es más facil recordar `0x30` que `48`. Así pues para convertir un caracter numérico en su dígito correspondiente habrá que restarle ese valor:

```
int v = cadena[0] - 0x30;
```

O si prefieres la solución legible...

```
int v = cadena[0] - '0';
```

Ahora bien, si resulta que solo quieres convertir los dígitos numéricos tendrás que identificar dichos dígitos:

```
if( cadena[0] >= '0' && cadena[0] <= '9' )
  v = cadena[0] - '0';
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola Con la función stoi conviertes string a un numero entero de cualquier base así por default esta en base 10

```
#include <iostream>   // std::cout
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(){

string cadena="32";
int i_dec =stoi (cadena);
cout<<i_dec<<endl;
}
```